# How to access child views in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native.
I have used a `Flat Grid` and I want to access a Image component `on click event`. I want to update its image and I am unable to access that image tag.
On click of gird item I want to update image src.

Scenario :-

I have got list of recipes and on click of these I want show them selected by making the Icon to tick.

below is Flat Grid I have used.

```
<FlatGrid
itemDimension={130}
items={this.state.recipie_listing}
renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
<TouchableOpacity               
onPress={() => this.AddRecipe(index, item.id)}>
<View>
<ImageBackground
style={{
height: 250,
width: "100%"
}}
  imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10 }}
  source={{
  uri: item.image
 }}
>
<Icon
name={this.state.icon_name}
style={{
color: this.state.icon_color,
position: "absolute",
right: 2,
top: 2
}}
/>

<View
style={{
backgroundColor: "rgba(220, 222, 224, 0.8)",
height: 60,
width: "100%",
borderBottomEndRadius: 10,
borderBottomStartRadius: 10,
flexDirection: "row",
justifyContent: "center",
alignItems: "center",
position: "absolute",
bottom: 0 
}}
>
 <CustomText
style={{
marginStart: 10,
marginEnd: 5,
color: "white",
fontSize: 15,
fontWeight: "bold"
}}
>
 {item.name}
</CustomText>
</View>
</ImageBackground>
</View>
</TouchableOpacity>
)}
/>
```

Comment: Hey, Vaibhav provide some code example so that it will be easy to help on your specified issue.

Comment: @PrazSolver thank you for showing interest I am made changes in the post I hope i may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, add a state variable like showImage to false and then

In AddRecipe method call the setState method and toggle the variable value and then where you want to load the image src add conditional rendering
here is a code example

```
  state = { showImage : false}
  ------
  AddRecipe = () =>{
      this.setState({
         showImage:!this.state.showImage   
      })

  render(){
    return(
      ----------
     <ImageBackground
        style={{
        height: 250,
        width: "100%"
        }}
        imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10 }}
        source={{
        uri: this.state.showImage === true ? src1 : src2 
        }}
      >
      ----------
     )

  }
```

I think that will help you as far as I understand your problem.